# Require wp-load.php breaks website - possible Multisite issue

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to write some code to access the WordPress database.
Everything tells me to load wp-load.php to do this.
However I just get critical errors when I do.
This used to work a couple of months back, not sure when it stopped working, so might be a recent WordPress update that has stopped this working. Currently on WordPress 6.1.1

```
<?php

ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' );
ini_set( 'display_startup_errors', '1' );
error_reporting( E_ALL );

global $_SERVER;
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']   = 'www.mydomain.com';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/';

$file_require = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/wp-load.php';
include $file_require;

if (file_exists( $file_require )) {
    echo 'FILE EXISTS: file_require: ' . $file_require . '<br>';
} else {
    echo 'FILE NOT FOUND: file_require: ' . $file_require . '<br>';
}

echo 'Successfully Loaded wp-load.php<br>';
```

The code after the include nevers gets executed.
Just get a "There has been a critical error on this website."

The site is a MULTISITE and some articles and similar questions do suggest that this may be teh cuase. But this used to work just fine and this has always been a multisite. As I say, this has stopped working during the last few weeks.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: WordPress overrides PHP's error settings. I'd recommend turning WP_DEBUG on in wp-config.php in order to see the specific error message. In the long run, however, I'd recommend using an officially supported method of interacting with WordPress, either a custom WP CLI command, or a plugin. For the latter, you just need to register "something" that is specific to your code, WordPress will boot normally and then call your code. You'll have access to 100% of WordPress features and objects, but you can also just do regular PHP stuff, too.

Comment: This is 100% a MULTISITE issue.
I've tried the above code in a single Wordpress site environment and it works perfectly, but when used on a MULTISITE, it fails as described.

Comment: That may be, but that also doesn’t change anything about my comment. Turn on WordPress debugging to see the error message. And, just my opinion, although you can totally manually boot WordPress from the outside (I’ve done it many times, regular and MS), it is so much easier to be on the inside already.